# Not getting return data from PHP script in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm learning how to integrate JQuery, AJAX and PHP together.

My problem is that my success function isn't getting any value from the parameter and just getting a '0'. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong either, but I have just been following this tutorial [JQuery & PHP Tutorial](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-day-15-part-2/) and just copied how he got the value from the PHP code using echoes and a parameter variable r.

I have tried searching for the solution, but I'm not sure if any of the results are relevant to what I am doing. I tried following some of their advice but none seems to work (the promise thing for jQuery)

I hope someone can enlighten me what I am doing wrong as I am eager to learn more PHP and jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        jQuery("form").submit(function(e) { 
             var input = $("#input").val();
             var url = 'input=' + input;
             $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "process.php",
               data: url,
               success: function(r) {
                   $("#output").text(function(r) {
                        return r;
                   });
               }
             });
             e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        Inputs:<br />
        <textarea rows="15" cols="60" id="input" name="input">Some text...
        </textarea><br /><br />
        Start:
        <input type="text" id="start" name="start" />
        End:
        <input type="text" id="end" name="end" /><br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <p id="output">Output: Some Random Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
require 'parser.php';
$parser = new Parser();
#header('index.php');
$hash = $parser->parse($_POST['input']);
$keys = array_keys($hash);
foreach($keys as $key) {
    echo "$key ->";
    $dests = $hash[$key];
    foreach($dests as $dest) {
        echo " $dest";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        jQuery("form").submit(function(e) { 
             var input1 = $("#input").val();
             var url = {'input' :  input1};   // a little change to the data parameter
             $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "process.php",
               data: url,
               success: function(r) {
                //   $("#output").text(r);  //<--- changed to this
                   $("#output").html(r);  // this is better as you output html
               }
             });
             e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

for jquery text(), use the return value from the server directly.   If you are outputting html use jquery html() instead

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. It's working now. I'm just curious what exact part of the code was wrong and why? Was it because I passed the output after receiving it from the server or was it because of the wrong format of the data?

Comment: @Chad  jquery .text() method only takes a string as an argument, not a function.